# A question about cin (two calls for one input?)

Tags: c++, cin

I'm dealing with C++ a bit and am following an introduction in which this code snippet makes me wonder a bit:

```
cout << "\nPlease enter an article label: ";

// Input the label (15 characters maximum):
cin >> setw(16);       // or: cin.width(16);
cin >> label;
```

The authors don't tell me why for one input line I need (or can use) two times `cin`, one with the manipulator and one with the place to modify?

Now, in chapter 4 about streams, according to what I've read up to now, I would have expected that these are two separate instances and therefore actions performed. Therefore, at my naive stage, I would have written:

```
cin >> setw(16) >> label;  // according to: cout << setw(16) << label;
```

Could you explain to me, why two times `cin` result in just one input line? It seems, that the proposed similar questions here are not similar enough - after checking them.

I can simply accept and reproduce it. But I would like to understand it.

Is it just because in the first line with `cin` there is no place to write the input two thus it creates the field and which then is "used" from the cin in the second line? And if so, is there a good reason for splitting it in two lines like this?

Comment: `cin >> setw(16); cin >> label;` does the exact same thing as `cin >> setw(16) >> label;`. Just two different ways to write the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. But why does it work (two times cin)?

Comment: @DemihmSeinname "But why does it work (two times cin)?" - because in both cases first you change some internal state of `cin` and then you read some input that utilize that state. Whether that happens in one line or two is irrelevant.

Comment: @DemihmSeinname The `cin` object saves the value used with `setw`. It then uses that value when you input a value (and then forgets the saved value).

Comment: I'm not sure the duplicate is exactly relevant.  If the question is about why it is two statements instead of one, then the duplicate applies.  But if you're wondering why there are two _things_ that got streamed with `cin` (`setw(16)` and `label`) but only one input was captured, then it's because `setw` is an _io manipulator_ which controls the way the next operation is performed. (and this is not addressed by the duplicate)

Comment: Thank you all. I'm still confused, but maybe only because of three ways of expressing the same. If all three ways are equivalent - cin.width(16); cin >> label; as well as cin >> setw(16); cin >> label; and simply cin >> setw(16) >> label; - I wonder what exactly happens "under the hood", what cin exactly is and in which situations might which way be preferable?
Thus, yes: The question is *how* it works. My "why" was inaccurate.

Comment: The I/O manipulators are just a convenient way of pipelining modifications to the stream state within a chain of operations. The documentation for [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) explicitly states its relationship to the `width()` function for streams. The different ways of using these really boil down to style and personal preference.

Comment: `std::cin` is an object (correct: a global instance of a class). It has internal state (probably member variables). The `operator>>` is overloaded multiple times where the first argument is always of the class type of `std::cin` (or actually a base class of it), and the second one of the supported types. The I/O manipulators (like `setw()`) are special types so that a special overload is used. These overloads change the state of their istream object in the first argument.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Apparently, it is simply too early to understand the complex concepts behind it. So for now, I will simply accept that there are these ways and maybe (much) later I can reconstruct the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
cin >> setw(16);
cin >> label;
```

Performs the same as:

```cpp
cin >> setw(16) >> label;
```

It works like this:

- `cin >> setw(16)` is performed first.

  `setw(16)` creates an implementation-defined object that holds the value `16`. This object is then passed to an overloaded `operator>>` that takes in `cin` and that object, assigns the object's value to `istream::width()`, and then returns the `istream&` that was passed in, which is our `cin`.

  Something to the effect of this:

  ```cpp
  struct _setw_type { int value; }

  _setw_type std::setw(int value) { return {value}; }

  std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, const _setw_type &obj) {
      stream.width(obj.value);
      return stream;
  } 

  // cin >> setw(16) is the same as
  // operator>>(cin, setw(16))
  ```
- After that, the next operation to deal with is `label`, and since `cin` was returned from the first operation, what's left is simply:

  ```cpp
  cin >> label
  ```

Comment: Your first bullet point is wrong.  `std::setw()` does not invoke the `operator>>` overload that takes a `std::ios& (*)(std::ios&)` function pointer, as you claim. `setw()` returns an object of *implementation-defined* type to hold the value `16`, and then it overloads `operator>>` to accept that type. That overload then calls `cin.width()` with the stored value. The `operator>>` overload for `std::ios& (*)(std::ios&)` is used only with non-parameter manipulators, like `std::endl`, `std::fixed`, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I messed up by copying the wrong overload. I corrected it. If it's still wrong, I think I'll need to delete the answer because it's bedtime :-)

Comment: Your update still referred to the `std::ios& (*)(std::ios&)` overload. I have corrected it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There was no reference to `std::ios& (*)(std::ios&)` left that I can see but I'm thankful for the edit anyway :) Perhaps the part where I showed `istream& operator>>( std::istream&(*func)(std::istream&) ) { return func(*this); }` could have been kept, or was that a distraction perhaps?

Comment: "*There was no reference to `std::ios& (*)(std::ios&)` left that I can see*" - I saw it: "*`setw(16)` creates an implementation defined object that holds the value 16. **This object is then passed to the inherited `istream` member function `istream& operator>>( std::ios&(*func)(std::ios&) );` The implementation defined objects is here seen as `func`**...*" `setw` does not use the `operator>>` overload that takes a function pointer. "*Perhaps the part where I showed ... could have been kept*" - It was completely wrong info to begin with, which is why I took it out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The was still an `std::ios` reference in v2 but it was removed in v3. In v4 I added `istream& operator>>( std::istream&(*func)(std::istream&) ) { return func(*this); }` which is more or less what it says that the operator will be doing on cppreference. I don't think that's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256822/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 0):

The "two calls" are to `std::ifstream::operator>>` (in fact two *different* overloads of that function name).  `cin` is not a "call" it is an `istream` object upon which the `>>` operation is performed twice.

Both the two *statement* and single statement form have the same ultimate effect on the `cin` object. `>>` is an operator and splitting the expression into two statements is no different than say transforming:

```cpp
a += b + c ;
```

to

```cpp
a += b ;
a += c ;
```

in that any expression involving more than one operator can be split into sub-expressions.